# can cv::convexHull be applied to double-precision points data

Tags: c++, opencv, convex-hull

The following code works fine:

```
typedef cv::Point cvp;

    std::vector <cvp> points{ cvp(0, 0), cvp(1, 0), cvp(0, 1), cvp(0.5, 0.5) };
    std::vector<cvp> hullPoints;

    cv::convexHull(points, hullPoints);
```

However, when I change the definition of `cvp`:

```
typedef cv::Point2d cvp;  // cvp is now a double-precision point
```

the program crashes on entering the `cv::convexHull` procedure. Looks like 
either `cv::convexHull` may be called only for integer-valued points, or I am doing something terribly wrong.

I found nothing on this issue in OpenCV documentation.

Answer (score 3):

`convexHull` works only with `Point2i` (same as `Point`) and `Point2f`.
See the [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9a18330f3a1a5eddb5e4f23e8daa9534d83fa8c6/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp#L137) for reference:

```
CV_Assert(total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S));
```

So you can work with floating point values, but they must be `float`, not `double`:

```
typedef cv::Point2f cvp;
```